# What is the least damaging creature in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So there are a number of exploits that require an enemy nearby, but for the case of armor or blocking skills you need to be getting hit. So I was curious. Of all the creatures in Skyrim, that will attack you, what does the lease damage? Per hit or Per minute.

I'm not interested in any solutions that require the use of the console or mods.

Comment: I understand *why* you want to use the [tag:xbox-360] tag, but if you look at that tag's wiki, it should be clear that it's not appropriate for this question. Asking for a solution that doesn't require mods or the console is relevant to a broad swath of players, including many on platforms *other* than the 360.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz The only other platform that this is relevant to, that I know of, is the Ps3. What many other platforms am I missing? I looked at the wiki and have seen this battle on several other games and will address this issue or find a question that does in the meta.

Comment: There are PC players who, for whatever reason, don't want solutions requiring the console or mods as well. I didn't say "many other platforms," I said "many players on other platforms". Subtle but important distinction.

Comment: So as I understand it then, unless it is a console specific issue like lag on the PS3, cross console games like this should use no system tag even if they ask for console commands because while console commands are unique to PC the PC tag does not say "game features truly unique" only "PC specific problems" which to me would cover things like PC specific lag but not console commands.

Comment: More or less. The other edge cases where you'd want to use a platform tag is if, for instance, the PS3 version had an extra bonus dungeon not available in the 360 or PC versions, or if your question specifically was *seeking* a solution based on console commands, which are exclusive to the PC version. Put another way: use the platform tags if the answers you want **would only apply** to that platform, not if you would like the answers to **at a minimum apply** to at least this platform - the latter case should be specified in your question, not via tags.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I had assumed those cases as well. Thanks for taking the time to explain all this to me.

Comment: So you don't want to use mods or the console, but you're using exploits?  ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @GnomeSlice I see how you could be confused. I care not about mods or the console because PS3 and Xbox360 do not have access to them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The least damaging creature is probably the humble Mudcrab.

That said, Armor and Block skills level up based on how much damage they prevent, not how many times they're used (this is the opposite of Oblivion's system), though the mudcrab should be just fine for leveling conjuration and alteration.

Comment: The least damaging should technically be the Rabbit since they can't attack but can be hostile (if you cast fury on them.) :P

Comment: I'd agree that mudcrabs are weakest (and hostile naturally) but as Raven kindly pointed out they are not good for leveling block/armor. I believe giants are best for leveling block and armor, if you can survive their hits that is. You can also level restoration while you are at it. There are various youtube video showing this.

Comment: Yeah I know it is a slow process but currently when i run into a Mudcrab I let it hit me while I heal myself and when I run out of magick I kill it and move on, but I was curious if it was something else? @yx. Can the chicken attack?

Comment: Rabbits have the Fuss-Roh-Hiss shout with zero damage output, which does terribly terribly scare.

Comment: skeletons in the hall of the dead in Whiterun work up both nicely and they respawn after you kill them the next day so you can just kill one of them (out of 3) and the other two typically cannot do more damage than your natural regeneration.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't actually need to be hit (for instance, for Conjuration leveling with Bound Weapon spam, or Alteration): A Slaughterfish can be kept 'in combat' with you without ever actually being able to attack if you position yourself properly at the edge of the water.

If you do need to be hit (for armor skills, or block), a Mudcrab will do the least damage, but you'll level more effectively and efficiently by finding the strongest mob that you can sustainably heal yourself through getting beaten by. Defensive skill leveling is based on *damage taken* (or mitigated), not by attacks received.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's probably a rabbit that would have been forced to attack you by using the "frenzy" spell on it and being the only target around.